# Hibernate+PostgreSQL - Attempting to retrieve join table/composite primary key information from database. No result found for query

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, join, hql

I'm trying to further understand database retrieval.
My goal is to find the Category Name of a Film based on the film.id and make a query to find it. The result I got back is an error:

`jakarta.persistence.NoResultException: No result found for query [SELECT c.name FROM Category c JOIN FilmCategory fc ON c.id = fc.id.categoryId WHERE fc.id.filmId = :filmId] at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:476) at client.PartTwo.main(PartTwo.java:41)`

The film table is unaware of the relationship. The category table is unaware of the relationship. The only table aware is Film_category, which contains both primary keys film_id and category_id. The name of the category can be found through finding the film id and then retrieving the category id associated with that film id, grabbing that category object and then retrieving the category name attribute from category entity.

I believe this is a join table, but no sides are aware of the relationship except for the film_category. I cannot change the database itself as it is not mine. (it's not a real database, it is dummy data, but from an SQL course. )

Here is my code for this so far:

**Client class:**

```
package client;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import entity.film.Category;
import entity.film.Film;
import entity.film.Language;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;
import util.HibernateUtil;

public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction txn = session.getTransaction();
        try {
            txn.begin();

            // Film
            Film film = session.get(Film.class, 2L);
            System.out.println(film);
            // Language
            Language language = session.get(Language.class, 2L);
            System.out.println(language);
            // Film category
            // Need a join table
            
            Long filmId = 123L; // Replace with the desired film ID

            String hqlQuery = "SELECT c.name " +
                              "FROM Category c " +
                              "JOIN FilmCategory fc ON c.id = fc.id.categoryId " +
                              "WHERE fc.id.filmId = :filmId";

            String categoryName = session.createQuery(hqlQuery, String.class)
                    .setParameter("filmId", filmId)
                    .getSingleResult();

            System.out.println("Category Name: " + categoryName);

            // Category
            // Film Actor
            // Actor

            txn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (txn != null) {
                txn.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Film class:**

```
package entity.film;

import java.util.Date;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Version;

@Entity
public class Film {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "film_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 255)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "release_year")
    private int releaseYear;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id")
    private Language language;

    @Column(name = "rental_duration")
    private int rentalDuration;

    @Column(name = "rental_rate")
    private double rentalRate;

    private int length;

    @Column(name = "replacement_cost")
    private double replacementCost;

    private String rating;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date lastUpdate;

    @Column(name = "special_features")
    private String specialFeatures;

    private String fullText;

    public Film() {
    }

    public Film(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getReleaseYear() {
        return releaseYear;
    }

    public void setReleaseYear(int releaseYear) {
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }

//
    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(Language language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public int getRentalDuration() {
        return rentalDuration;
    }

    public void setRentalDuration(int rentalDuration) {
        this.rentalDuration = rentalDuration;
    }

    public double getRentalRate() {
        return rentalRate;
    }

    public void setRentalRate(double rentalRate) {
        this.rentalRate = rentalRate;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public double getReplacementCost() {
        return replacementCost;
    }

    public void setReplacementCost(double replacementCost) {
        this.replacementCost = replacementCost;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public String getSpecialFeatures() {
        return specialFeatures;
    }

    public void setSpecialFeatures(String specialFeatures) {
        this.specialFeatures = specialFeatures;
    }

    public String getFullText() {
        return fullText;
    }

    public void setFullText(String fullText) {
        this.fullText = fullText;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Film [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", releaseYear=" + releaseYear + ", language=" + language
                + ", rentalDuration=" + rentalDuration + ", rentalRate=" + rentalRate + ", length=" + length
                + ", replacementCost=" + replacementCost + ", rating=" + rating + ", lastUpdate=" + lastUpdate
                + ", specialFeatures=" + specialFeatures + ", fullText=" + fullText + "]";
    }

}
```

**FilmCategory**

```
package entity.film.jointables;

import java.util.Date;

import entity.film.Category;
import entity.film.Film;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.MapsId;
import jakarta.persistence.Version;

@Entity
public class FilmCategory {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private FilmCategoryId id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("filmId")
    @JoinColumn(name="film_id")
    private Film film;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("categoryId")
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;
    
    @Version
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date lastUpdate;

    public FilmCategory() {
    }

    public FilmCategoryId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(FilmCategoryId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Film getFilm() {
        return film;
    }

    public void setFilm(Film film) {
        this.film = film;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
    
    

    
}
```

**FilmCategoryId**

```
package entity.film.jointables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class FilmCategoryId implements Serializable {

    private Long filmId;

    private Long categoryId;

    public FilmCategoryId() {
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(categoryId, filmId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        FilmCategoryId other = (FilmCategoryId) obj;
        return Objects.equals(categoryId, other.categoryId) && Objects.equals(filmId, other.filmId);
    }

    public Long getFilmId() {
        return filmId;
    }

    public void setFilmId(Long filmId) {
        this.filmId = filmId;
    }

    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    
}
```

**Category**

```
package entity.film;

import java.util.Date;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Version;

@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date lastUpdate;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

}
```

**Here's a representation of what the film_category table looks like in the database, with the information I am trying to connect with a JOIN to retrieve the Category name of the film with ID 123**

| film_id | category_id | last_update |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 16 | 2006-02-15 10:07:09 |

category_id links to the category.name column in the category table, And pretend that the value returned is "Sci-fi".